# Laravel, ajax, csrf

Tags: javascript, laravel

Возникла проблема с отправкой токена в Laravel.
Токен вот здесь:

```
<meta id="_csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Форма:

```
<form id="auth" method="POST" onsubmit="return AuthValidator(this)">
    <input type="text" id="login" name="login" value="">
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="passw" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="logged" value="Login"><br>
</form>
```

Ajax запрос:

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//в url - маршрут laravel
        xhttp.open('post', window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + "/auth");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token.content);
        xhttp.send("login="+form.login.value+"&passw="+form.passw.value);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
```

Сам back-end:

```
if ($request->IsMethod('post')):
    $this->main();
    elseif($request->IsMethod('get')):
        if(View::exists('public.auth')):
            return view('public.auth');
            else: return view('page404');
            endif;
    endif;
```

Ошибка: TokenMismatchException.
Вариант - отключить проверку токена не подходит.
Всем благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код работает, использовал в своем проекте на Laravel

html:
обрати внимание на атрибут name тега meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

js:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name = "csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});

jQuery.ajax({
    //ajax запрос
});
```

Comment: изменил код на такой:
 `$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name = "csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
  });
  $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + "/auth",
   data: {login: form.login.value, password: form.passw.value}
  });` 
Не помогло.

Comment: тег meta изменил?

Comment: да, изменил. По документации смотрел. Laravel всёравно возвращает ошибку: 
`TokenMismatchException`. В консоле: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: покажите хедеры из самого запроса (из панели разработчика chrome)

Comment: @n.osennji
`Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`
Ошибку токена не выбивает, но в консоль выводит: `500 (Iternal Server Error)`

Comment: @Владислав значит допустил ошибку где-то в коде php. Попробуй с помощью ajax обратится к методу в контроллере который просто выводит единицу (echo 1) и выведи результат в консоль.

Comment: @VIncent , всё решил ошибка была в коде js.

Answer (score 0):

**Используйте Laravel X-CSRF-TOKEN**

Посредник VerifyCsrfToken будет также проверять заголовок запроса X-CSRF-TOKEN. Например, вы можете хранить токен в HTML-теге meta:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

После создания тега meta вы можете указать библиотеке, такой как jQuery, автоматически добавлять токен в заголовки всех запросов. Это обеспечивает простую, удобную CSRF-защиту для ваших приложений на базе AJAX:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

По умолчанию файл resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js регистрирует значение мета-тега csrf-token в HTTP-библиотеке Axios. Если вы не используете эту библиотеку, то вам нужно будет вручную настраивать это поведение для своего приложения.

https://webzone.kz/publication/laravel-csrf-protection